# Dynamically add Items into middle of array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

So this is my orignal array in PHP

```
$data = array(
  "results" => array(
    "course" => "$cc",
    "books" => array(
      "book" =>
      array(  
      //Place temp here;  
      )
    )
  )
);
```

This is where i have more data to go in the middle of the array, it could be hundreds or maybe just even one

```
foreach ($my_array as $counter => $bc) {
        $temp = array(
          "-id" => "$id[$counter]",
          "-title" => "$title[$counter]",
          "-isbn" => "$isbn[$counter]",
          "-borrowedcount" => "$borrowedcount[$counter]"
        );
    }
```

So it can be encoded in a valid JSON way to look like

```
{
 "results": {
  "course": "CC167",
  "books": {
   "book": [
    {
      "-id": "585457",
      "-title": "Beginning XNA 20 game programming : from novice to professional",
      "-isbn": "1590599241",
      "-borrowedcount": "16"
    },
    {
      "-id": "325421",
      "-title": "Red Hat Linux 6",
      "-isbn": "0201354373",
      "-borrowedcount": "17"
    },
    {
      "-id": "424317",
      "-title": "Beginner's guide to darkBASIC game programming",
      "-isbn": "1592000096",
      "-borrowedcount": "46"
    },
    {
      "-id": "437390",
      "-title": "Objects first with Java : a practical introduction using BlueJ",
      "-isbn": "0131249339",
      "-borrowedcount": "89"
    },
    {
      "-id": "511094",
      "-title": "Objects first with Java : a practical introduction using BlueJ",
      "-isbn": "2006044765",
      "-borrowedcount": "169"
    }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you for any help you can offer

Comment: array_splice() (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) is the function you're looking for

Comment: What is the specific part you are having problems with?

Comment: $data['results']['books'] += array(//something)

Answer (score 3):

Assign the `book` array element to the value of `$temp` once you've looped and added all the values.

```
$data['results']['books'] = $temp;
```

Or, loop first and when you set your `$data` array when you already have the values you need:

```
$data = array("results" => array("course" => "$cc", "books" => $temp));
```